# .NET Core 3.1 read Assembly's File Version

Tags: c#, .net-core-3.1

in my console app, I need to load the File Version value of some external assembly.

```
var assembly1 = Assembly.LoadFrom("my.dll");
var assembly2 = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath("my.dll");

var versionNumber = assembly1.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

and here's the thing - if I use the `var assembly1 = ...` or `var assembly2 = ...` then I get the nasty error message

**Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'**

when invoking the `GetCustomAttribute` method, but if the both lines are being used, then everything works fine. So, how to fix it to be able to use the `var assembly1 = ...` or `var assembly2 = ...` ?

Comment: Because of that you are loading "my.dll" into running app. so "my.dll" needs another assembly you didn't load like on the error. (mvc.core).
Use FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo("my.dll").FileVersion from system.diagnostic to avoid error.

Comment: @anilcemsimsek you're right, thanks, it works. I checked the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core, and there is no version 3.1.0.0. That's strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo` doesn't try the load the entire DLL into the app:

```
System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo fvo = 
    System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(@"my.dll");

string versionNumber = fvo.FileVersion;
```

If you build `my.dll` with `dotnet build -p:Version=4.4.4`, `versionNumber` will be equal to "4.4.4.0" in the above sample code.

Answer (score 0):

the following code is normal, please check the path is correct.

```cs
 private const string AssemblyPath = "C:\\Users\\test.dll";
 var assembly2 = AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromAssemblyPath(AssemblyPath);
 var versionNumber = assembly2.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```

or

```cs
 private const string AssemblyPath = "C:\\Users\\test.dll";
var assembly1 = Assembly.LoadFrom(AssemblyPath);
var versionNumber = assembly1.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>().Version;
```